# How I set an ui text value to a register from Firebase in Unity?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm working in a school project using Unity and Firebase where I need to display the username of the current user in a Text box.

I´m already get the data from Firebase but when 
I try to set the userNameText's text to it, nothing happens.

This is my code:

Variables:

```
private DatabaseReference reference;
private string userName;
public Text userNameText;
```

Initialization:

```
void Start()
    {
        //database reference (I'm hiding the project id)
        FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://projectID.firebaseio.com/");

        // Get the root reference location of the database.
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;

        GetUserData();
    }
```

GetUserData():

```
public void GetUserData()
    {
        reference.Child("users").Child(PlayerPrefs.GetString("userUID")).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.Log("something was wrong");
            }
            else if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> results = (Dictionary<string, object>)task.Result.Value;
                userName= (string)results["userName"];
                Debug.Log(userName);
                userNameText.text = userName;
            }
        });
    }
```

When I run the project, it just display the userName in the console but the text box has not yet been updated.

Comment: Not having enough code (see [mcve] for info) what data do you have in results?

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but the property from the textbox is wrongly spelled, its Text with capital T, but this should have been catched by the compiler

Comment: No, it's not. The property is lower case 't'. So `userNameText.text` is correct

Comment: @BugFinder each user has these attributes: userName(string), xp(int)

Comment: But is that whats in the dictionary.. shew the dictionary contents

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to move your void method into an IEnumerator and set your reference to a variable.

```
IEnumerator GetUserData(){
    var getTask = reference.Child("users").Child(PlayerPrefs.GetString("userUID")).GetValueAsync();
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => getTask.IsCompleted || getTask.IsFaulted);
    if (getTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> results = (Dictionary<string, object>)task.Result.Value;
        userName= (string)results["userName"];
        Debug.Log(userName);
        userNameText.text = userName;
    }
}
```

And then in your start method, you can start the coroutine. I also had the same issue with my text box disappearing. If you put up some log statements, you can see the first pass through your function reads before the call to firebase is made, and sets the text to an empty string.

```
void Start()
{
    //database reference (I'm hiding the project id)
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://projectID.firebaseio.com/");

    // Get the root reference location of the database.
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;

    StartCoroutine(GetUserData());
}
```